# Why does the following method with Calendar APIs in Java work?

Tags: java, calendar

I have the following method that has been for a very long time in a legacy codebase.

```
public static Calendar nowAsCalendar(String timeZone){
   Calendar FDRCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(timeZone);
   FDRCal.setTime(now());
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(1, FDRCal.get(1));
   cal.set(2, FDRCal.get(2));
   cal.set(5, FDRCal.get(5));
   cal.set(11, FDRCal.get(11));
   cal.set(12, FDRCal.get(12));
   cal.set(13, FDRCal.get(13));
   cal.set(14, FDRCal.get(14));
}
```

We are setting a brand new Calendar instance cal that uses the default timezone so I think it should break as we are not setting the timezone in the new Calendar instance. Am I overlooking something?. What is the best way to set the current date with a timezone?

Comment: What do you mean by "work" and "break"? Please explain your expectations and show what your code actually outputs. Also the method is missing a return statement.

Comment: Sorry I updated my post. The intent of the code is to set the current time with timezone

Answer (score 1):

In `Calendar.getInstance()` the new instance uses your system's default time zone, so failing to set it the time zone won't cause anything to break, unless you require the time zone to be something other than the default.

However, `Calendar` is an obsolete class with many flaws, and it's really best not to use it any more.  The more modern class to represent a date and time with a timezone is `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

You can instantiate one of these, using the default time zone and the current date and time, by writing `ZonedDateTime.now()`.  There's also a version where you can pass in a `ZoneId` for a time zone, if you want a different time zone from the default  - that is, you can write something like

```
ZoneId sydneyTime = ZoneId.of("Australia/Sydney");
ZonedDateTime rightNow = ZonedDateTime.now(sydneyTime);
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my post. The intent of the code is to set the current time with a timezone.

Comment: Sorry for the typos when I first typed this.  I got distracted partway through.  I think it's OK now.